# Can I search in an Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure-storage

I want to store the addresses of thousands of people. The address is typical name, address, city etc... I want to then search for first name, last name, city etc...

Can I use Azure Table Storage and use it's API to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments regarding indexing your table using Azure Search are excellent, if you don't mind paying the hefty monthly fee.

To answer your question, you can search using the Azure Storage API, but you've got to be very intentional about what fields you want to search when structuring your Azure Storage Tables initially.

The only "indexes" you have to work with are the partition and row keys. Entities with the same partition key are stored together and can be searched efficiently if the partitions are not large. Since Azure Tables do not enforce a schema, you can actually store the same data under different partitions to make search easier.

Assume you had the address Johnny Appleseed 839 Sherman Oaks Drive Knoxville, TN 37497. You could duplicate this data in the same table with the partition keys:

- citystate-knoxville_tn_37497
- name-appleseed_johnny
- street-sherman_oaks

When your user tries to search, choose a partition based on the criteria that the user entered, then Azure will perform a full partition scan to find all matching records. You'll also need to deal with continuation tokens.

You can also limit to a partial partition scan if you specify your row key within a partition to be part of the search criteria. Azure will scan only rows that could potentially match the row key.

Comment: This is a good answer about denormalizing data and data models based on your different query needs. There is unfortunately one more thing you need to deal with which is consistency (only if you care that is :) Azure does not provide out of the shelf support for atomic batch operations on different partition keys. Have a look at here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#eventually-consistent-transactions-pattern

Comment: Dogu, You are absolutely right. Thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Storage Table only has two indexed properties: PartitionKey & RowKey. Querying on non-indexed properties will trigger a whole table scan. If you only need to store several thousands of records, Azure Storage Table is a good option due to its low price. However, if you're going to store much more records, I'd suggest you to choose SQL Azure since it supports advanced indexed query.